# Is there a canonical way to connect a topological space?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, connectedness

It is known that each topological space $X$ admits a Hausdorffization - which means that every topological space can be "approximated" by the corresponding unique Hausdorff space for which each continuous mapping from $X$ to a Hausdorff space factors uniquely through the Hausdorffization.

For given topological space is it possible to connect it in a canonical way, i.e. to find a corresponding connected space with the property as above?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it is not true. Consider $X = \{0,1\}$ a set with two elements, endowed with the discrete topology. Suppose there were a connected space $X'$ and a continuous map $i : X \to X'$ such that for all connected spaces $Y$ and for all continuous maps $f : X \to Y$, there exists a unique map $f' : X' \to Y$ such that $f' \circ i = f$.

Then first I want to show that $i$ is injective. For this consider $f : X \to [0,1]$ the inclusion. Then there exists a unique map $f' : X' \to [0,1]$ such that $f' \circ i = f$. But $f$ is injective, therefore so is $f'$ (consider that if $i(0) = i(1)$, then $f(i(0)) = f(i(1)) \implies 0 = 1$).

Next I want to show that $i$ is surjective. Let $Y = \{a,b\}$ be a set with two elements, endowed with the trivial topology (the only open sets are $\varnothing$ and $Y$). Consider $f : X \to Y$, $f(0) = a$, $f(1) = b$. Then $f$ is continuous, hence there exists a *unique* map $f' : X' \to Y$ such that $f' \circ i = f$.
Now suppose to the contrary that $i$ weren't surjective. Then I can find two different continuous maps $f' : X' \to Y$ such that $f' \circ i = f$. Either I can send all the elements of $X' \setminus \{i(0), i(1)\}$ to $a$, or I can send them to $b$, while in both cases I map $i(0) \mapsto a$ and $i(1) \mapsto b$. That's a contradiction, hence $i$ is surjective.

It follows that $i$ is bijective, and $X'$ has two elements, $i(0)$ and $i(1)$. But if I consider again $f : X \to [0,1]$ the inclusion, then I find that $i(0)$ and $i(1)$ must be separated by open sets (the preimages of, say, $[0,1/4)$ and $(3/4,1]$ by the induced map $f' : X' \to [0,1]$). Hence $X'$ is actually discrete, which is contradictory with it being connected.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I can tell, *no.*

If you mean canonical to mean a left adjoint to the full inclusion of categories, in the sense that it is dual to $\mathrm{Conn} \hookrightarrow \mathrm{Top}$, then it has to preserve coproducts, which cannot occur by  [Qiaochu's answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66650/connectifications).

The idea is to consider a two point space, which is the coproduct of two one point spaces in $\mathrm{Top}$, but there is no coproduct in the category of connected spaces.

You can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571543/is-there-a-coproduct-in-the-category-of-path-connected-spaces) for an elaboration for the case of path connected spaces.

If you google "connectification of topological spaces" some papers show up discussing various constructions.

Comment: Damn. Beat by... About 6 years and a half!

Comment: @NajibIdrissi well your answer is perfectly nice, and follows directly from elementary universal property arguments, so +1 anyhow