# Is the coproduct in a subcategory of topological spaces with coproducts always the disjoint sum?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Suppose a subcategory $C$ of topological spaces has all coproducts. Is that coproduct always equal to the disjoint sum topology?

Notes:

- If $C$ happens to be a coreflective subcategory of a category $D$, then I believe all colimits in $C$ are those of $D$. This is because the inclusion functor is left adjoint, and so preserves colimits. So the question is more about non-coreflective subcategories.
- In general, a subcategory of topological spaces [may not have](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1571543/51161) even finite coproducts.

Comment: I would suspect, *no*, but can't prove it. I mean, it all comes down to whether or not a disjoint union of spaces in $C$ is again an object of $C$, and there are easy to state things that break down there e.g. the category of connected spaces (but I don't think that category has coproducts so it shouldn't be a counterexample)

Comment: By subcategory, do you mean full subcategory?

Comment: @S.C. I'll accept any kind :)

Comment: @kaba I think topological groups should be a counterexample then. That won't be full, and thus not a reflective subcategory. (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5095/what-are-the-product-and-coproduct-in-the-category-of-topological-groups))

Comment: @S.C. Possibly yes. The problem then becomes to prove that the coproduct for topological groups is not homeomorphic to their disjoint union topology. Perhaps that can be shown by comparing cardinalities of the underlying sets.

Comment: @S.C. So if $X$ is a group with two elements, then the disjoint union of two $X$'s has 4 elements, while the free product of two $X$'s has infinitely many elements. And $X$ can be given the trivial topology to make it a topological group. I guess that answers the question.

Comment: Doesn't a subcategory consisting of a single object and a single morphism give a trivial counterexample?

Comment: @kaba: The terminal category occurs as a full subcategory generated by a one point space in Top.

Comment: @Z.A.K. Yes, realized that too. However, do these categories have coproducts?

Comment: @kaba: It's a poset category and coproduct in a poset category is just a least upper bound. So yes, the terminal category has all co/products.

Comment: @Z.A.K. Right. I think for non-triviality there should be the added requirement that for a given set of spaces, there exists a space whose underlying set is the disjoint union of the underlying sets of those spaces, to be able to form the disjoint union topology at all.